# DBT transform that escapes equal sign at beginning of varchar

Tags: dbt

In order to avoid CSV injection (e.g. = at start of field) - still happens in CSV if opened in Excel

Is there a way in DBT to apply a transformation to each and every column.

Comment: Could you add a minimum reproducible example about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Great question and never really thought about it. Could definitely go two ways though - avoiding excel formula injection from inputs (sanitization) and applying a transform to every column. Going to give both a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution base on my research. This is perfectly fit base on my requirements as describe @tconbeer.

1. I have data in a sql database, and some cells contain strings that start with =
2. I am using dbt to model data in our database
3. I want to COPY or export that data in our database to a CSV
4. I want to open that CSV in Excel

This DBT macro will remove all special characters that are possibly use in CSV injection attacks like '=','@','-','+'. See https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/CSV_Injection

Here is my solution:

```
    {% macro sanitize_csv(value_to_sanitize) -%}
        {{ 
            dbt_utils.replace(
                dbt_utils.replace(
                    dbt_utils.replace(
                        dbt_utils.replace(value_to_sanitize,"'='", "''"),
                         "'+'", "''"),
                     "'-'", "''"), 
                "'@'", "''") 
        }}
    {%- endmacro %}
```

For me this is a bit cleaner than using `case when` like suggested by @tconbeer. I don't know if its faster though but for me its good solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question to be:

1. You have data in a sql database, and some cells contain strings that start with `=`
2. You are using dbt to model data in your database
3. You want to COPY or export that data in your database to a CSV
4. You want to open that CSV in Excel

As part of step (2), you want to make sure that no cells start with `=`, so that when you export your data to CSV and open it in Excel, Excel doesn't interpret the cell as a formula.

For any field I wanted to "santize" in this way, I'd use `replace` and wrap that in a case statement (you didn't tag your RDBMS, so postgres syntax here):

```sql
case
    when my_field like '=%'
    then replace(my_field, '=', '''=') -- adds single quote before equals
    else my_field
end as my_field
```

(you could use `regexp_replace` to ensure you're only replacing `=` at the beginning of the string if that is important to you, and of course you could replace with the empty string instead of `'=` if you prefer)

In dbt, you could wrap this in a macro:

```sql
{% macro excel_sanitize(field_name) %}
case
    when {{ field_name }} like '=%'
    then replace({{ field_name }}, '=', '''=') -- adds single quote before equals
    else {{ field_name }}
end as {{ field_name }}
{% endmacro %}
```

And then call it in your model like:

```sql
select
    {{ excel_sanitize("my_field") }},
    {{ excel_sanitize("my_other_field") }},
    {{ excel_sanitize("my_third_field") }},
...
```

Comment: Wow thank you for your answer. But why not replace it with just an empty string value like ''?.

Comment: Adding a single quote before the `=` makes Excel treat the following text as an ordinary string, not a formula